# IF Function to show two different answers depending on the Value in Cell?

Tags: excel, formula

Good evening all,

I am trying to get the following formula correct, I have a table that will display an inspection date, if the date is entered I would like another cell to display that date but plus 180 days, also if the cell is blank that the other cell display `N/A`, I have that bit working but can't seem to get the date part to work?

`=IF([@[Date of Inspection ]]="","N/A",H2)`

Comment: A true date is Just a numeric value and you can plus it by 180 just fine. What exactly does your data looks like?

Comment: Yes I get that part, ok let me try again, I have an inspection date in cell D2, I would like H2 to show that date plus 180 days which would be the next inspection date, but if there is no date in cell D2 that cell H2 shows 'N/A'. The part I have so far is this, =IF([@[Date of Inspection ]]="","N/A",H2). now i want to add, if Date of inspection is 11/11/2019 then H2 = 11/11/2019 + 180

Comment: To understand try: `=H2+180` in any cell... That is if H2 holds your date

Comment: Ah ha, no D2 holds the date, H2 is the next inspection date hence the + 180 days, but if there is no date on D2, I would like H2 to show N/A

Comment: try to put this in H2  : `=IF(D2="","N/A",D2+180)`